# Can anyone help me to finde the error in code?

Tags: linux, if-statement, terminal

I need help to find the appropriate way to write my conditional statement because it is not working.

```sh
cumonth= date +%m
cudinamic=
    
if [ $cumonth =10 ];
then
    cudinamic=a
elif [ $cumonth =11]; 
then
    cudinamic=b
elif [ $cumonth =12];
then 
    cudinamic=c
else
    cudinamic=$cumonth 
fi
    
#Echo display message
$echo $ytday  
$echo $cmonth 
echo "$cudinamic"
```

Comment: You need to wrap the commands in `$()` in order to have them executed and the results saved to the variables. Also please post actual code, not images, so people can copy an reproduce the issue.

Comment: cumonth= date +%m
cudinamic=



if [ $cumonth =10 ];
then
cudinamic=a
elif [ $cumonth =11]; 
then
cudinamic=b
elif [ $cumonth =12];
then 
cudinamic=c
else
cudinamic=$cumonth 
fi

#Echo display message

$echo $ytday  
$echo $cmonth 
echo "$cudinamic"

Answer (score 0):

To save the output of a command, use command substitution `$(...)`:

```
cumonth=$(date +%m)
```

The arguments to `[` must be separated by spaces, spaces aren't optional:

```
elif [ "$cumonth" = 11 ];
```

Note that there are 4 parameters: `"$cumonth"`, `=`, `11`, and `]`. It's a good habit to quote the variable, in case it's empty or contains spaces, it will still be considered a single word.